# Why is XOR much faster than OR?

Tags: performance, assembly, rust

Here is a benchmark:

```rust
fn benchmark_or(repetitions: usize, mut increment: usize) -> usize {
    let mut batch = 0;
    for _ in 0..repetitions {
        increment |= 1;
        batch += increment | 1;
    }
    batch
}

fn benchmark_xor(repetitions: usize, mut increment: usize) -> usize {
    let mut batch = 0;
    for _ in 0..repetitions {
        increment ^= 1;
        batch += increment | 1;
    }
    batch
}

fn benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let increment = 1;
    let repetitions = 1000;

    c.bench_function("Increment Or", |b| {
        b.iter(|| black_box(benchmark_or(repetitions, increment)))
    });
    c.bench_function("Increment Xor", |b| {
        b.iter(|| black_box(benchmark_xor(repetitions, increment)))
    });
}
```

The results are:

```
Increment Or            time:   [271.02 ns 271.14 ns 271.28 ns]
Increment Xor           time:   [79.656 ns 79.761 ns 79.885 ns]
```

I get the same result if I replace `or` with `and`.

It's quite confusing as the `or` bench compiles to

```
.LBB0_5:
        or      edi, 1
        add     eax, edi
        add     rcx, -1
        jne     .LBB0_5
```

And the `xor` bench compiles to basically the same instructions plus two additional ones:

```
.LBB1_6:
        xor     edx, 1
        or      edi, 1
        add     eax, edi
        mov     edi, edx
        add     rcx, -1
        jne     .LBB1_6
```

[Full Assembly code](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/9snvds)

Why is the difference so large?

Comment: The or variant is being unrolled, the xor not.  Realise that `increment |= 1` is an idempotent operation but `increment ^= 1` is not.

Comment: *even more instructions* — # of instructions are a weak indicator of performance, at best.

Comment: *compiles to* ... you are confused. Both methods are ~35 lines of assembly, not 4 or 6.

Comment: @Shepmater Thanks for pointing out inaccuracies in my question. I improved the language of the question. my "even more instructions", I meant "the same instructions + two additional ones". I understand that it doesn't predict performance, but the result is somewhat counterintuitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This part of the function that uses XOR which you quoted:

```
.LBB1_6:
        xor     rdx, 1
        or      rsi, 1
        add     rax, rsi
        mov     rsi, rdx
        add     rcx, -1
        jne     .LBB1_6
```

Is only the "tail end" of an unrolled loop. The "meat" (the part that actually runs a lot) is this:

```
.LBB1_9:
        add     rax, rdx
        add     rdi, 4
        jne     .LBB1_9
```

`rdx` is set up to be 4 times `increment` - in a way that I would describe as "only a compiler could be this stupid", but it only happens outside the loop so it's not a complete disaster. The loop counter is advanced by 4 in every iteration (starting negative and counting up to zero, which *is* clever, redeeming the compiler somewhat).

This loop could be executed at 1 iteration per cycle, translating to 4 iterations of the source-loop per cycle.

The loop in the function that uses OR is also unrolled, this is the actual "meat" of that function:

```
.LBB0_8:
        or      rsi, 1
        lea     rax, [rax + 2*rsi]
        lea     rax, [rax + 2*rsi]
        lea     rax, [rax + 2*rsi]
        lea     rax, [rax + 2*rsi]
        add     rdi, 8
        jne     .LBB0_8
```

It's unrolled by 8, which might have been nice, but chaining `lea` 4 times like that really takes "only a compiler could be this stupid" to the next level. The serial dependency through the `lea`s costs at least 4 cycles per iteration, translating to 2 iterations of the source-loop per cycle.

That explains a 2x difference in performance (in favour of the XOR version), not quite your measured 3.4x difference, so further analysis could be done.

Comment: It's interesting that the xor in the loop has been optimized out, since the compiler apparently realized that xor'ing a value with 1, 4 times (or for that matter any even number), is a no-op.  However it didn't take the obvious next step and optimize out the (now-empty) loop itself, to replace it with a single multiply.